# Moving an UIView when UIButton is pressed

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, sdk, uibutton

my view hierachy is following:

```
BigView
- UIScrollView
  - View 1
  - View 2
  - View 3
- UIView
  - UIButton
```

now i want, that when i press the UIButton, the BigView (which includes the button as well) moves 100px to the top (so parts of the BigView aren't visible any longer) and another UIView gets visible at the free space under the BigView.

You get the problem? :)

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "which includes the button as well"? A `UIView` can only have a single parent.

Comment: just that the button is in a subview of big view. but important is, how i can move a view animated to the top, that it gets cut up on top and theres free space on the bottom.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just do a UIView animation in the method you call when the button is clicked:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
self.BigView.frame = CGRectMake(newXPoistion, newYPosistion, samewidth, sameheight);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

That will animate the bigview to the new cooridinates you give and should move everything within that view aswell

Answer (score 5):

If you want an instant move (without animation) you can do it like this:

```
CGRect rect = someView.frame;
self.someView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 3

```
  let rect = someView.frame

  self.view1.frame = CGRect(x: view1.frame.midX, y: 400, width: rect.width, height: rect.height)
```

**// Or**

```
 rectHeigh = someView.frame.height
 rectWidth = someView.frame.width

 view1.frame = CGRect(x: view1.frame.midX, y: 400, width: rectWidth, height: rectHeigh)
```